# Fading a background on a view to have a timer start

Tags: android

So far in my app I have a ImageView next to a Start button.  When the start button is pressed the ImageView is replaced by a TextView to start a countdown.  Ideally what I am trying to accomplish now is having the Image next to the start button and when the Start button is pressed the background of that image fades just a little bit and a countdown starts in the middle of that image which is not faded.

The only thing I can think of at the moment is to have a TextView and have the image as the background but then my question now is how to fade that background.  Would this be an ideal/correct way of doing this?  If so how would I go about fading the background?  If there is another way of doing this how would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a text view and image view with the image view on top then fade the image view then fade the image view on the button click by using setAlpha on the image view.

There are other ways like using a drawable list but this will save u more work.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha(float)